# Как получить элемент константной мапы?

Tags: c++, map

Создаю глобальную константную мапу и пытаюсь взят её элемент через опертаор [ ] в константную переменную, но компилятор говорит, что так нельзя. Какие ограничения не позволяют компилятору это сделать? Т.е. интересует именно причина, а не то как это обойти.

```
const std::unordered_map<int, string> MapWithModulesNames{
    {1, string{"LegacyBssManager"}},
    {2, string{"BsSettings"}},
};

int main() {
    const string a = MapWithModulesNames[1];
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: В данном случаи вы получаете отображение числа 1, а еслиб вы хотели получить отображение числа  5, то оператор [] должен возвращать ссылку на  пустую строку. Но это уже не будет константным обьектом, поэтому для константных map  не применим оператор []

Answer (score 5, accepted):

У `std::map` нет константного `operator[]`, потому что этот оператор создаёт элемент карты, если такого ключа ещё нет в оной. Если нужен доступ именно к существующему элементу, тогда нужно использовать `at`.

Answer (score 2):

Проблема в том, что оператор `[]` неконстантный, и возвращает неконстантную ссылку. Поэтому к константному `unordered_map` он неприменим...